# Views in list are not at the corrects size

Tags: android, listview, layout, size, height

I have a list view and an adapter. My problem is that the rows in the list are always `"wrap content"` even though I specifically stated the height as `"150dp"`.

This is my adapter:

```
private class LiveEventsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View contentView = convertView;
        if (contentView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            contentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.live_match_row, null);
            TypefaceManager.getInstance(LiveMatchActivity.this).assignTypeface(contentView);
        }

        if (events != null) {
            Event event = events.getEventsList().get(position);

            TypefaceManager typefaceManager = TypefaceManager.getInstance(LiveMatchActivity.this);
            TextView eventText;
            TextView minute;
            ImageView eventIcon;

            minute = (TextView) contentView.findViewById(R.id.live_match_minute);
            if (event.getOrientation().equals("home")) {
                eventText = (TextView) contentView.findViewById(R.id.home_team_event_text);
                eventIcon = (ImageView) contentView.findViewById(R.id.home_team_event_img);
            } else {
                eventText = (TextView) contentView.findViewById(R.id.away_team_event_text);
                eventIcon = (ImageView) contentView.findViewById(R.id.away_team_event_img);
            }
            minute.setText(event.getMinute() + "\'");
            eventText.setText(event.getDescription());
            minute.setTypeface(typefaceManager.getTypeface("bold"));
            eventText.setTypeface(typefaceManager.getTypeface("bold"));
        }   
}
```

That's how I `"setadapter"`:

```
ListView eventsListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.live_match_list);
        eventsListView.setAdapter(new LiveEventsAdapter());
```

and that's my `rows layout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="150dp"
android:background="@drawable/background_button" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/live_match_minute"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="82&apos;" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/home_team_event_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/home_team_event_img"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:paddingLeft="4dp"
    android:paddingRight="4dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/home_team_event_img"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/live_match_minute" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/away_team_event_img"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/live_match_minute" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/away_team_event_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/away_team_event_img"
    android:paddingLeft="4dp"
    android:paddingRight="4dp" />
```

Why is it that the rows in my list are always set on the same size, no matter what I put in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will NOT work.

This is what you should do.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background_button" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/live_match_minute"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="82&apos;" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Basically, add another layout and specify the height to that layout.
When working with adapter views specifying a height for the root layout doesn't work.